# how to add color to circle in driver class (java)

Tags: java, colors

```
    public class Driver
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            double circumference;
            double radius = 5.5;
            double pi = 3.1415926;
            double area = 0;

            Circle circleobject = new Circle();

            //Get Radius
            System.out.println("Circle's Radius");
            radius = keyboard.nextDouble();

            System.out.println("New Circle Object");

            Circle circle = new Circle();

            System.out.println("Area of Circle: " + Circle.getArea());
            System.out.println("Circumference of Circle: " + Circle.getCircumference());

        }
    }
```

I do not understand how to make the circle a colored one. Whether it be red, green or blue. what do i have to add in order to make the circle any color? Also, it seems that i cannot create a circle object with the line Circle circleobject = new Circle();
what am i doing wrong?
This is my circle class.

```
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;

    /**
    * A Circle is a figure that has a radius, a circumference, 
    * and an area. 
    * @author Kelvynn Cayanan 
    * @version 02/09/2014
    */
    public class Circle
    {

        // Constants
        public static final double pi = 3.1415926; 

        // instance variables
        private double circumference;
        private double area; 
        private double radius;
        private Color color;


        /**
        * Constructs a circle of radius aRadius
        * @param aRadius is the radius of the circle
        */
        public Circle(double aRadius, Color type)
        {
             radius = aRadius; // assigns value to radius
             circumference = ( 2 * pi * radius); // arithmetic for circumference
             area = ( pi * radius * radius); // arithmetic for area
             color = type; // displays type of color

        }

        public void draw (Graphics circle)
        {
           circle.setColor (color);
        }

        /**
         */
        public double getRadius()
        {
            return radius;
        }

        public double getCircumference()
        {
            return circumference;
        }

        public double getArea()
        {
            return area;
        }

        public Color getColor()
        {
            return color;
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is in Circle Class ?

Comment: You need to get input for a the color also. Then `setColor`, assuming you already have a `setColor` defined in your `Circle` class.

Comment: @Sanjeev i edited it so my circle class is there as well.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

You are not able to create circle using `new Circle()` because there is no zero argument constructer in your Circle class, so you have to use `new Circle(radius,color)` constructer.

Secondly for drawing a colored circle you need to make a circle in your draw method, something like this:

```
Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
Ellipse2D.Double cir = new Ellipse2D.Double();
cir.width = 2*radius;
cir.height = 2*radius;
cir.x = <upper left x co-ordinate>;
cir.y = <upper left y co-ordinate>;
g2d.draw(cir);
g2d.setPaint(color); // setting fill color
g2d.fill(cir);
```

And while calling you need to create a `JFrame` in your main program and create a `new circle` in its paint method and call `circle.draw(graphics)` method by passing `paint's graphics`

Hope this helps